# Deep well water tank leaking from gauge

Tags: pressure, leaking, gauge

Why is it leaking here and how can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The gauge does not appear to be leaking - the water seems to be coming from a point below the gauge on the fitting the gauge is screwed in to. Could you take a picture from a point a bit lower and to the right more clearly showing that? You can [edit] your post to add the link to it.

Comment: Looks like something fell off.  Do you find anything on the floor?  Would probably be hiding under nasty looking stuff, and be small.

Comment: It looks like a drain bolt fell off.  Would probably replace the nut that is still on also.  A local plumbing supply store should have both pieces.  Remove the nut piece and take it with you.

Comment: Is that the port that goes to the pressure switch? Is the pump constantly running? Or dose it have a safety? An over pressure safety that is failing? That looks like an old diaphragm tank after fixing the leak it may be getting close to replacement time, I mention this because upgrading to a bladder tank will be more efficient and they are smaller.

Answer (score 1):

So, what is now the third picture:

[image: picture from original post]

appears to show a tube that should be connected to this fitting. It's more or less the correct size, as opposed to the "clearly does not go here" garden hose in the picture that is now fourth.

[image: picture from original post]

Presumably, that tube needs to be reconnected, which appears to require repair. It's not 100% clear from the pictures, but is seems the tube may have broken just beneath the fitting (nut) that held it in place. If that's the case, removing the old nut and getting a new compression fitting of the same size from the hardware store should allow for repair. You may want to replace the whole tube, as it might be brittle from old age and vibration.

Comment: I added in the pics I believe you were referring to, just in case they should ever get reorganized again.